# Proving nonregularity

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

Suppose I have a language L = {wxwR} where wR is the reverse of w, w and x has minimum length of 1, w can consist of either 0's or 1's, while x can only consist of 1's.

How do I prove that this language is not regular? Is there any other way than using the pumping lemma? If using the pumping lemma, I'm still figuring out what x,y, and z I should pick for the string s=xyz, I would appreciate if you give me any hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take another look into how to use the pumping lemma. You have to pick a string `s`, such that for each partition `x`,`y`,`z`, one of the pumping lemma conditions is violated.

So, let `n` be the "pumping-lemma-number". Pick `s= 0^n 1 0^n`.
From 1) you know that `|xy| <= n`. From 2) you know that `|y|>=1`. Thus `y` only contains `0s`.

Following 3) `uv^2w` has also to be in `L`, but the first block of `0s` is longer than the second one. This means 3) is violated and thus `L` is not regular.